# @const in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I was reading http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml when I noticed in the Constant section with the annotated comments:

```
/**
 * The number of seconds in each of the given units.
 * @type {Object.<number>}
 * @const
 */
```

and then the guide goes on with "This allows the compiler to enforce constant-ness."

Is this a v8 thing? where is this documented?

*My mind is giddy with the possibility that maybe, just maybe, i can provide v8 (or whatever) with type information!*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Google's [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) can accept [JSDoc comments](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html), and it will generate warnings or errors.

For example, if you [try](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to compile the following code with the *Advanced Optimization*:

```
/** @const */ var MY_BEER = 'stout';

MY_BEER = 'bar';
```

It will generate an error:

> **Number of errors: 1**
>
> JSC_CONSTANT_REASSIGNED_VALUE_ERROR: constant MY_BEER assigned a value more than once at line 5 character 8

They discourage the `const` keyword because it is not part of the ECMAScript Standard.

Comment: Interestingly, I got this error message when (in error) setting location to change the URL when I should have been setting location.href.  The error message was less obvious at first glance:  'constant location assigned a value more than once...'  So, this error ALSO APPEARS for non-uppercase assignments!

Answer (score 3):

There is a const keyword in Javascript, but it isn't recognised by Internet Explorer so you can't really use it.

That's why Google's Javascript style guide recommends either using upper-case letters for a constant, or placing @const into a documentation block.

Both these techniques are advisory only and place no actual restrictions on the code.

Note that when you "compile" some code using [**Google's Closure Compiler**](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) that "compiler" will look at such things in the comment blocks and even generate warnings and errors.  But this is separate to running the code unmodified in an actual Javascript interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

[const (MDC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/const)

And: [const (the page you linked...)](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Constants#Constants)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but the current version of Closure Compiler will handle the `const` keyword quite well, as it will just replace it with `var` and understand that the variable is a constant.

For example, with advanced mode (`--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`) and polyfill rewriting (`--rewrite_polyfills`, this one's important, as mentioned earlier, "[don't use] `const` keyword because it is not part of the ECMAScript Standard", but this rewrites it as `var` so that it plays nicely with older browsers)

```
const get_selected_text = (/** @return {function():string} */ function() {
    if (window.getSelection || document.getSelection) {
        return function () {
            const selection = /** @type {function():Object<string,?>} */ (window.getSelection || document.getSelection)();
            if (typeof selection['text'] === "string") {
                return selection['text'];
            } else {
                return selection.toString();
            }
        };
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
        return function () {
            return document.selection.createRange().text;
        };
    }
    return function () {
        return '';
    };
})();
```

comes out looking like

```
var i=window.getSelection||document.getSelection?function(){var a=(window.getSelection||document.getSelection)();return"string"===typeof a.text?a.text:a.toString()}:document.selection&&"Control"!==document.selection.type?function(){return document.selection.createRange().text}:function(){return""};
```